# How to remove falsy values from array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an array of objects like so,

```
const arr = [
 {                                       
  'first name': 'john',               
  'last name': 'doe',            
  age: '22',                            
  'matriculation number': '12349',      
  dob: '12/08/1997'                     
},                                      
{                                       
  'first name': 'Jane',               
  'last name': 'Doe',            
  age: '21',                            
  'matriculation number': '12345',      
  dob: '31/08/1999'                     
},                                      
{                                       
  'first name': '',                     
  'last name': undefined,               
  age: undefined,                       
  'matriculation number': undefined,    
  dob: undefined                        
}                                       
]
```

I want to remove the last object from the array since it has falsy values, I tried to achieve this by writing a simple function like so

```
function removeFalsy(obj) {
  for (let i in obj) {
    if (!obj[i]) {
      delete obj[i]
    }
  }
  return obj
}
```

That didn't fix the issue, I also tried to use

```
arr.map((a) => Object.keys(a).filter((b) => Boolean(b)))
```

but that just returned the keys in the object, how can I achieve this, please?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming that you want to remove all object with falsey values, you can use `Array.prototype.filter` on the input array, as well as `Array.prototype.every` to check entry values for being falsey

```js
const arr = [{
    'first name': 'john',
    'last name': 'doe',
    age: '22',
    'matriculation number': '12349',
    dob: '12/08/1997'
  },
  {
    'first name': 'Jane',
    'last name': 'Doe',
    age: '21',
    'matriculation number': '12345',
    dob: '31/08/1999'
  },
  {
    'first name': '',
    'last name': undefined,
    age: undefined,
    'matriculation number': undefined,
    dob: undefined
  }
];

const result = arr.filter((el) => Object.values(el).every(Boolean));
console.log(result)
```

Comment: the question specificaly says that `want to remove it since it has falsy values` 0's are falsey, if we have to specify that age can be 0 and names can be empty strings then it's just a matter of rewriting the every callback function to check for it
EDIT: someone complained that a child with age of 0 would also be removed, but delteted it later, thus that comment

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 const noFalsies = arr.filter( ( element) => {
        const props = Object.values(element)
        return ! props.some( (aProp) => !aProp)
      }
      )
```

Comment: If there´s at least one property in the object undefined, the array element won´t be pass the filter

Comment: it's the same as my answer as checking if every element is not falsey is the same as checking if not a single one is falsey, they both will iterate over the same amount of elements, the only difference is that you approach requires a negation on every element and every element value